# SQL Server DATEPART

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the `AdventureWorks2012` sample database.

I am trying to calculate the quarterly total transaction amount for the year 2006 using the `datepart` function. And I need the `SEASON` column to return 1,2,3,4 not just 3,4 and the `TOTAL` column to return values

```
0, 0, 83537.4000000, 134826.4400000
```

I am sorry if this is confusing to look at, it is my first time using stackoverflow. Please help!

Here is the code:

```
WITH GROSSINCOME AS
(
    SELECT 
        A.ORDERID, 
        SUM((B.QTY * B.unitprice * (1 - B.DISCOUNT))) + A.FREIGHT AS    TOTAL,
        A.orderdate
    FROM 
        SALES.Orders AS A 
    JOIN 
        SALES.OrderDetails AS B ON A.orderid = B.orderid
    GROUP BY 
        A.orderid, A.freight, A.orderdate
)
SELECT 
    DATEPART(QUARTER, orderdate) AS SEASON,
    SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL
FROM  
    GROSSINCOME 
WHERE 
    YEAR(orderdate) = '2006'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(QUARTER,orderdate);
```

Comment: not quite sure exactly what you want but I would not be shocked if you are rounding B.Discount up to 1 and causing it to multiply by 0.  We can't really help unless you show us your sample data, what your results were and what your expected results are.  check the FAQ under help for more info.

Comment: `YEAR(orderdate)` returns an **int** value - so why are you putting (unnecessary) single quotes around it in your `WHERE` clause?? Just use  `YEAR(orderdate) = 2006` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to fix Dark code, the below code should work.

```
WITH GROSSINCOME AS
(
SELECT A.ORDERID,SUM(B.QTY*B.unitprice*(1-B.DISCOUNT)) + A.FREIGHT AS TOTAL,
A.orderdate
FROM SALES.Orders AS A JOIN SALES.OrderDetails AS B
ON A.orderid=B.orderid
WHERE YEAR(A.orderdate)='2006'
GROUP BY A.orderid,A.freight,A.orderdate
)

SELECT T.VAL AS SEASON,
SUM(ISNULL(TOTAL,0)) AS TOTAL
FROM GROSSINCOME
        RIGHT JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4))as T(VAL) ON T.VAL =  DATEPART(QUARTER,orderdate)
GROUP BY T.VAL;
```

Comment: thank you a lot. So it is possible to just right join values? and make the values = the datepart? can you explain please?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WITH GROSSINCOME AS
(
SELECT A.ORDERID, SUM((B.QTY*B.unitprice*(1-B.DISCOUNT))) + A.FREIGHT AS TOTAL,
A.orderdate
FROM SALES.Orders AS A JOIN SALES.OrderDetails AS B
ON A.orderid=B.orderid
GROUP BY A.orderid,A.freight,A.orderdate
)

SELECT T.VAL AS SEASON,
SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL
FROM GROSSINCOME
        RIGHT JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4))as T(VAL) ON T.VAL =  DATEPART(QUARTER,orderdate)
WHERE YEAR(orderdate)='2006'
GROUP BY T.VAL;
```

Comment: @Hogan : Available in SQL Server too

Comment: You should explain the "trick" you are doing to make sure all 4 quarters are visible.

Comment: This is  what i need as my output:
SEASON       TOTAL
----------- ---------------------
1  0.00
2  0.00
3  83537.40
4  134826.44

Comment: @jchao : please update your question with table structure and desired output

Comment: thank you a lot. So it is possible to just right join values? and make the values = the datepart? can you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

check this query just modified yours, it will return 4 rows with seasons from 1,2,3,4 and their total

```
;WITH GROSSINCOME AS
(
    SELECT 
        A.ORDERID,SUM((B.QTY*B.unitprice*(1-B.DISCOUNT))) + A.FREIGHT AS TOTAL,
        A.orderdate,DATEPART(QUARTER,orderdate) AS season,YEAR(orderdate) orderyear
    FROM 
        SALES.Orders AS A JOIN SALES.OrderDetails AS B
    ON A.orderid=B.orderid
    GROUP BY A.orderid,A.freight,A.orderdate
)
SELECT 
    season,SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL
FROM GROSSINCOME 
WHERE orderyear=2006
GROUP BY season;
```

Answer (score 0):

I discourage the use of common table expressions (CTEs) unless there is an advantage or need for them. There simply is no advantage or need for a CTE in the query within the question.

As Dark Night has shown, the solution to your quandary is to simply have 4 rows, one for each of the four quarters. There are many ways to provide those rows, a very simple union query could do it. Here is a re-write that avoids the use of CTE and uses a simple union all query for the 4 rows.

```
SELECT
      q.n AS Season
    , d.total
FROM (
      SELECT 1 AS n
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4
    ) AS q
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  DATEPART(QUARTER, O.orderdate) AS qtr
                , SUM((OD.QTY * OD.unitprice * (1 - OD.DISCOUNT))) + O.FREIGHT AS TOTAL
            FROM SALES.Orders AS O
                  JOIN SALES.OrderDetails AS OD ON O.orderid = OD.orderid
            WHERE O.orderdate >= '20060101'
                  AND O.orderdate < '20070101'
            GROUP BY
                  DATEPART(QUARTER, O.orderdate)
      ) AS d ON q.n = d.qtr
```

I would also encourage you to NOT use functions in your where clauses. I have removed the use of *YEAR(A.orderdate)='2006'* and replaced it with **sargable predicates** that will permit access to an index on the orderdate column.

```
WHERE O.orderdate >= '20060101' AND O.orderdate < '20070101'
```